# Have you Ever heard about `renderThing` pattern?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

When I was developing web app with React, I met a situation that I have to render some JSX conditionally.

But I don't want a large return statement. So I created some functions like this:

```
const Example = (props) => {
  const renderThing = (someCondition) => {
    if (someCondition) {
      return (
        <div>{...anything!}</div>
      )
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {renderThing(props)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is this an anti-pattern? I heard about this pattern called `renderThing` in [this article](https://dev.to/jcutrell/react-anti-pattern-renderthing-50nd)

But the article's example is a class component. And I'm using `renderThing` in the functional component. So I think it can be different.

Is `renderThing` pattern is an anti-pattern?

Comment: Depends; I don't think there's a generic answer--it depends on context.

Comment: I believe it’s just conditional rendering. You can lazy load the components also such that only the component that meets the condition is loaded in memory.

Comment: The condition of whether or not to render shouldn't be within the function IMO. Then the `renderThing` function is really just another component and the owner of it can decide whether or not to render it.

Comment: @AWebb THX. Then, without the lazy loading, which one is better? Another component or `renderThing`.

Comment: @ChadS. THX. Now I think that extract `renderThing` to the another component is better!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it anti-pattern, though since `props` are always in scope they wouldn't need to be explicitly passed to a `renderThing` function. In fact, `renderThing` could just be the stored result of an expression.

```
const Example = (props) => {
  const renderThing = someCondition && <div>{...anything!}</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {renderThing}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```